# Dockerfile copies entire folder instead of the files in them

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

When I `exec` into the created container, not the files in `.` are copied but the folder is coppied into `/var/www/project`

So I wan't to have all my files in the `project` folder but instead the folder containing the files is copied to `project`.

I am using Mac OS, Docker 18.06.1-ce

/docker/docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./../
      dockerfile: docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    volumes:
      - ../.././:/var/www/project/
    networks:
      - symfony

  fpm:
    build:
      context: ./../
      dockerfile: docker/php/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ../.././:/var/www/project/
    networks:
      - symfony

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
      - 3311:3306
    networks:
      - symfony

networks:
  symfony:
```

/docker/nginx/Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.14

COPY ./docker/nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
COPY . /var/www/project
```

/docker/php/Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

COPY . /var/www/project
WORKDIR /var/www/project/
```

Comment: I'm not following you're question; it sounds like you're saying "I want to copy my files to project, but it's copying files to project"

Comment: I think he means he wants to copy every file in the local project, but instead of only copying the files it also copies the local project folder. Like: folder/files instead of just files